# Microcontroller with both ethernet and radio onboard?

Tags: microcontroller, ethernet, radio

Does anyone know of any (reasonably low-cost) SoC which combines **all** of:

- Microcontroller (any architecture, at least 4KB RAM/8KB flash)
- Radio transceiver (433MHz - 915MHz or 2.4GHz)
- Ethernet MAC + PHY

(For a wireless sensor application - connecting to low power sensor nodes)

I can find examples of micros with either peripheral, but not both:

Eg.

**Micro + ethernet:**

[LM3S9B9x](http://www.luminarymicro.com/products/lm3s9b96.html) = ARM Cortex-M3 + Ethernet MAC and PHY

[PIC18F66J6x](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en026447) = PIC18 + Ethernet MAC and PHY

**Micro + radio:**

[CC430](http://focus.ti.com/docs/prod/folders/print/cc430f6137.html) = MSP430 + Sub-1GHz radio

[EM250](http://www.ember.com/products_zigbee_chips_e250.html) = XAP2b + 802.15.4/ZigBee

Please only answer this question if you can name a chip.

Comment: I'm very interested in knowing if there is anything as well.

Comment: I could give you a good example of two chips that would accomplish this but I know of none that do both.

Comment: It's a shame that no one knows of a chip. Might just have to go with a 2 chip solution.

Comment: which wireless? zigbee?  what data rates for the ethernet?

Comment: 802.15.4 would be ideal, but Bluetooth, 433MHz/866MHZ/915MHz (DASH7 type stuff) is interesting too. 10mbit/s or higher for the ethernet

Comment: Wow, big bounty, I wish I had an answer.

Comment: @Kellenjb I wish I had an answer too

Comment: Maybe I should pull some strings with a friend at TI and have them post a fake part that is the CC430 with ethernet built in.

Comment: low power radio AND ethernet seems an odd combination. I don't think it's something that's common enough that there would be profit to be made to build a generic off the shelf part which combines them both. Pretty much any complex device is going to have multiple ICs in it, it's not something to avoid at all costs.

Comment: Could it be that it isn't possible to get one crystal frequency working with both?

Comment: @Thomas O two crystals would not be problem the LM3S9xxx uses a separate crystal for the ethernet to the processor

Comment: True, but adding an additional oscillator section adds cost, as does the crystal (for the end user.)

Comment: @Joby: I'm curious why you want such a device; unless you are *extremely* space constrained it will command an enormous premium in cost due to being incredibly application specific (low-volume).

Comment: @Nick I work for a company which produces a high volume, low cost device featuring radio and ethernet. We currently have a 2 chip solution. I can't find a single chip and thought people might be able to help. Hence, the very specific question and bounty :-)

Comment: TI has some Micro + Wireless + USB. None with ethernet though.

Answer (score 5):

The [MediaTek RT3050](http://www.mediatek.com/_en/01_products/04_pro.php?sn=1004) has what you need.

Comment: Interesting, I really hadn't considered wifi - as I'm looking to connect with low power sensor nodes

Comment: Ah, I didn't read carefully enough.

Answer (score 2):

Both together I've never seen.

ST has [STM32W](http://www.st.com/mcu/inchtml-pages-stm32w.html) that integrates a 2.4GHz transceiver and Freescale has [MC1322x](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=MC13224V&fsrch=1&sr=1) that integrates ARM7/Coldfire with 2.4GHz transceivers, but both don't have the ethernet PHY.

Comment: Both good chips, but they aren't what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Not really a chip, but would a [Digi ConnectPort](http://www.digi.com/products/wirelessdropinnetworking/connectportxgateways.jsp#overview) be a turnkey solution for what you have in mind?  You can run custom software (Python) on them to manage your wireless devices and communicate over Ethernet.

Comment: Interesting device, but not what I'm looking for